# Is it possible to have multiple FileServer handlers to return from different folders?

Tags: go

Hi there I got these handlers:

```
func StartHttpServer(ipAddr string) {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/printJson", PrintJsonHandler)
    mux.HandleFunc("/report", RaportHandler)
    mux.HandleFunc("/returnBalancesDates", ReturnBalancesDatesHandler)
    mux.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static")))
    mux.Handle("/readfiles/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./reports")))
    err := http.ListenAndServe(ipAddr, mux)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ERROR: Http Server crashed: ", err)
    }
}
```

But it seems the second FileServer handler doesn't return files from folder "reports" as I expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you set this up, the second fileserver is trying to serve `./reports/readfiles/file` when a request comes for `/readfiles/file`. If you want it to serve `./reports/file`, then do:

```
 mux.Handle("/readfiles/", http.StripPrefix("/readfiles/",http.FileServer(http.Dir("./reports"))))
```